# Comparing dates in Python using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

[image: Excel Doc]
in the below code, I am trying to compare dates in a column in my excel but getting this error:
2022-03-18 10:18:16' does not match format '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S'

```
for i in sheet2['G']:
 if i.value=='Transaction Time':
     sheet2['G1']='Transaction Time'
 elif i.value=='None':
    sheet2.delete_rows(i.row)
   
 elif datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.value),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')<date1:
    sheet2.delete_rows(i.row)

 elif datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.value),"%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")>date2:
    sheet2.delete_rows(i.row)
```

Comment: Why are you converting datetimes to strings and then back to datetimes? Also, deleting rows as you loop will cause you to skip rows.

Answer (score 0):

Just a typo i guess

```
 elif datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.value),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')<date1:
    sheet2.delete_rows(i.row)

 elif datetime.datetime.strptime(str(i.value),"%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")>date2:
    sheet2.delete_rows(i.row)
```

Your first one is good `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` but the second one, you inverted day and month format `"%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"`

Comment: After correcting, here is what I am getting. I have checked  the date column but can't find an input 'None' in the entry.      ValueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: Can you try commenting the delete_rows() ? Maybe try to print(i.value) instead and check what value you have. I may be the fact that you're deleting row that cause the issue. You're deleting rows and at some point, the value is None. Hard to tell with just the loop.

Comment: Btw, when you have to delete value from some sort of array / list, it's better to go in reverse, so deleting doesn't affect the next value in any case.

Comment: As suggested, I printed out and noticed that the loop actually printed all before complaining which shows that the program actual ran the loop before complaining.

Comment: can you suggest a better method. is it possible to convert the time format to just yyyy,mm,dd. The idea is to filter  the data by date. Any idea will be welcome

Comment: What do you mean "filter" ? Do you mean create another sheet with only the value between date1 and date2 ? Or juste display them on your console ?

Comment: Not really, I want just delete rows that are now within that date. The issue was that each line has a different time so use date== will not work as the different time will make them unique and i want to get all transaction for a particular day for calculation.... solve now though. Thanks alot

Comment: I think one of your best bet is to keep track of row where the date is out of your bound in a List, then delete them after. Probably not the more efficient, but i think this might be easy enough to implement to your current result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243220/discussion-between-engr-sule-muhammed-abba-and-vollfeiw).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it with just few lines of codes.

1. I removed the time on the date to make it easy for comparison with these codes:

   ```
      for i in sheet2['G']:
        for r in range (2,mr2+1):
           i.value=  str(i.value)[0:10]
      sheet2['G1']='Transaction Date'
   ```
2. With this success, I was able to filter any date I want using the following:

   ```
      for i in sheet2['G']:
        if str(i.value)!=date1:
          sheet2.delete_rows(i.row)
   ```

where date1 is a variable that I can modify or the app user can modify to get any day of interest.